# Angularjs: Setting a class on an element within ng-repeat based on a property of the current item

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a class on an element within `ng-repeat` and more importantly I want to decide which class is applied based on a property of the member of the model that is currently being iterated on. To illustrate, I have a list of buildings that I'm obtaining from a `REST` endpoint and then rendering them in the table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="building in buildings">
......
    <td>
        <i ng-class="{'icon-check' : building.elevator, 'icon-check-empty' : building.elevator}"></i>
          {{building.elevator}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The issue is that I'm failing to set the class on `<i>` element based on the value of the `elevator` property of the building that is being rendered.
For the record, `{{building.elevator}}` renders as `true` or `false` based on what came in the response.

I have also tried using a ternary operator in the class attribute with no luck.

Also tried using:

> building.elevator == 'true'/'false'

instead of just:

> building.elevator

with no result.
Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Thanks

**EDIT**
The issue was in the faulty class for Font Awesome, I have probably picked up a class that no longer exists while searching for something that looked like check/no check solution.

For reference, here is the code that works:

```
<i ng-class="{'fa fa-check-circle-o' : building.elevator, 'fa fa-circle-o' : !building.elevator}"></i>
```

and the relevant part of the server response I was getting:

```
[{..., "elevator":false, ...}]
```

Thanks Nikhilesh Shivarathri & user3273700 for your responses. You've helped me with alternatives and pointers which led me to suspect the faulty class in the end.

What do I do with my question now when the final answer wasn't even related to the code I presented here for inspection?

Comment: what is the type and value of building.elevator?

Comment: Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample application of your requirement please check if you're missing anything in your application from below example.

Change the `value.booleanField !== 'true'` to `value.booleanField !== true` if 
your data contains boolean fields not as strings.

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);

app.controller('samplecontroller', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [{
    booleanField: 'true',
    name: 'Jospeh'
  }, {
    booleanField: 'false',
    name: 'John'
  }]

});
```

```css
.test-false {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="samplecontroller">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
        <td>{{value.name}}<td>
        <td ng-class="{'test-false': value.booleanField !== 'true'}">{{value.booleanField}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```